# Is there a way to use Wavify with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gsap

I have been using a JavaScript library called Wavify(https://github.com/peacepostman/wavify) to create wave animations in my websites.

I recently started Learning React and wondered if I could use Wavify in my react projects by installing it with npm.

I have tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';
import {wavify} from 'wavify';
import './App.css';


function App() {

  let wave = React.createRef();

   let waveAnimation = wavify(wave, {
    height: 60,
    bones: 3,
    amplitude: 40,
    color: 'rgba(150, 97, 255, .8)',
    speed: .25
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="wave" ref={wave}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
App
C:/Users/*****/*****/myReactApp/src/App.js:14
  11 | 
  12 | let wave = React.createRef();
  13 | 
> 14 |  let waveAnimation = wavify(wave, {
     | ^  15 |   height: 60,
  16 |   bones: 3,
  17 |   amplitude: 40,
View compiled
▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your import expression is wrong. Try either of these `import wavify from 'wavify'`
**or** `import * as wavify from 'wavify'`

Comment: You might need to add the additional script tags in your index.html

Comment: FYI TweenMax/Lite is old. Just use `gsap`: [GSAP 3 Migration Guide](https://greensock.com/3-migration/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the React version of Wavify

[react-wavify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wavify)